# can i take the internet explorer favorites folder in windows and convert that to a single favorites file?

Tags: bookmarks

i want to convert this folder of links into a single file that can be imported into another browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, simply open IE and select `File > Import and Export`.  Then all you have to do is check `Export to a file`, click next, then check `Favorites` and click next two more times.  You will now be prompted to save `bookmark.htm` which is has all of your Favorites in it.  You can import this to virtually any browser.

Comment: I had to enable the Menu bar by right clicking on the Fav Bar first!